# Scope changes not shown in view when manipulated from inside a function

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I've got a problem where the scope changes are not being reflected in the view.

```
"use strict"

app.controller "DashboardController", ($scope, $http, $filter, $location) ->
  $scope.greeting = 'Hello from the dashboard!'

  $scope.time = ""

  $scope.updateClock = ->
    date = new Date()

    $scope.time = [date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds()].join(':')

  setInterval $scope.updateClock, 1000
```

That's the coffeescript code.

```
<div class="clock">
  {{time}}
</div>
```

That's what my view is.

The time just isn't displaying. If I set `$scope.time` at the beginning of the controller manually it does work fine but just not when it's inside a function. The compiled coffeescript looks like this:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  app.controller("DashboardController", function($scope, $http, $filter, $location) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello from the dashboard!';
    $scope.time = "";
    $scope.updateClock = function() {
      var date;
      date = new Date();
      return $scope.time = [date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds()].join(':');
    };
    return setInterval($scope.updateClock, 1000);
  });

}).call(this);
```

Why would it be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setInternal works outside of AngularJS's digest/working loop, so Angular won't know to perform dirty checking.  Use $apply to explicitly tell Angular to do this.

```
$scope.$apply(setInterval($scope.updateClock, 1000));
```

EDIT

Angular now has a wrapper for window.setInterval, and you should use that instead.  Inject $interval into your controller.  Then change the line to:

```
$interval($scope.updateClock, 1000);
```

Much better.

http://jsfiddle.net/nahpf/

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for :)

Comment: Problem being that $interval doesn't work with my version of angular for some reason :(

Comment: time to upgrade! OR make your own